# Call to shmat twice

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-memory

My program has 2 threads, I use shared memory to communicate between the two.

Each thread has an 'init' method. In the init method, I call 'shmget' and 'shmat' to get the shared memory segment and attach to local variable. A portion of the code is like below:

```
Thread 1 (which runs first):

void init() {
  this->segment_id = shmget(SAME_KEY,SAME_SIZE,IPC_CREAT|S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH);
  this->data       = shmat(this->segment_id,0,0);
}

Thread 2 (which runs after thread 1):

void init() {
  this->segment_id = shmget(SAME_KEY,SAME_SIZE,0);
  this->data       = shmat(this->segment_id,0,0);
}
```

The program is running but it gives unexpected result. What I'm afraid is that the call to 'shmat' in the second thread may make the 'data' in thread 1 inaccessible or some sort of malfunctionality. The fact is that, in thread 1 I can access the whole shared segment, but in thread 2 I can access only the first 16 bytes, so I don't know what's happening.

**Does this mean each shared memory segment can be attached to 1 location at a time?
Is it ok to call 'shmat' twice to make the shared memory accessible from different pointers?**

Comment: "in thread 2 I can access only the first 16 bytes" - what happens when you try to access the 17th byte? SIGSEGV, or something else?

Comment: Just a side note, the POSIX version using `shm_open()` and then `mmap()` is easier to use.

Comment: @SteveJessop: no errors occur, but, when thread 1 writes into the shared memory a bunch of data, let's say 1024 bytes, the thread 2 can read the values of only first 16 bytes, all the bytes after that are zeros

Comment: For communicating between threads in linux - you do not need shared memory. Within single process RAM is available to all threads in one process. Shared memory is for inter-process communication.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: yeah, but i have a thread in another process too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Each shared memory segment can be attached to multiple locations at a time. It ok to call 'shmat' twice to make the shared memory accessible from different pointers.**

I suspect that in the given example you can't be sure that Thread1::init() is called before Thread2::init() so in Thread2 you are accessing not created memory - so that is the reason for observed problems.

Use  IPC_CREAT for both calls (without IPC_EXCL of course).

See [manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/shmget.2.html)

Comment: uhm, i've found my mistake, i accidentally modify the shared memory data before triggering thread 2